# IBM Connections 4.0 CR4: Mail and Calendar are not working

Tags: email, calendar, lotus-domino, ibm-connections

I upgraded my Connections 4.0 to CR4. The mail and calendar widgets were working well previously. After upgrading to CR4, I found this error in the log file:

```
[9/17/13 12:31:01:458 CST] 0000006f Renderer I org.apache.shindig.gadgets.render.Renderer render The gadget at https://connserver/connections/resources/socmail-client/gadgets/inbox.xml did not render. The following error occurred: Unsupported feature: [socpim.rpc]
```

This resulted to not load the Connections Mail and Calendar. When mouse-hovered, it only says "Loading" forever. Has anyone encountered this problem? I have already inspected the Domino server, some related XML files and I can't seem to find the problem. I also have already searched in the internet related to this problem but I can't find anything. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please reinstall Connections Mail 1.0 FP1. It should be OK after that.